# 3 equals 51 in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I have played at writing a C# program.
It is to work out surface areas.

My problem is that the int is being displayed as I believe Unicode?
eg 3 is displayed as 51

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
double area;
double width;

Console.WriteLine("Please input width or Height of one side of cube");
width = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(width); // to check input
area = (width * width) * 6;

Console.WriteLine(area);
```

Am I using the wrong commands? or can it be reverted to the double the int is passed to?

Comment: what are you inputting?

Comment: i am inputting an int

Comment: Thanks

The answer was
    width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
instead of
    width = Console.Read();

Im still a little confused as I felt 
    .Read would output an int that would be converted to double.

I believe i am now taking in a string and converting to double?

Comment: I meant what numbers but yeah, Console.ReadLine() will retun a string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx